# MATLAB's legend behavior for unnamed datasets

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Below is a sample code. I don't want the 2nd legend item "data1" to show up. Any ideas how?

```
figure(1); 
plot(rand(20,1));
legend('Random values'); 
pt = rand(3,3)*10;
patch(pt(:,1), pt(:,2),pt(:,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by passing the named argument pair `'HandleVisibility', 'off'` when calling `patch`:

```
figure(1); 
plot(rand(20,1));
legend('Random values'); 
pt = rand(3,3)*10;
patch(pt(:,1), pt(:,2),pt(:,3), 'HandleVisibility', 'off')
```

The result:
[image: result]

Note that changing the handle visibility does have some other effects. See [MATLAB's documentation on hanlde visibility](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preventing-access-to-figures-and-axes.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to move the `legend()` call after all the plots. In this case, if your legend has `n` labels, they will be used for the `n` first plots in the figure:

```
figure
hold on
randPoints = rand(20, 3);
pt = rand(3,3)*10;

lbl = '';

for i = 1:4
    subplot(2, 2, i)
    hold on
    plot(randPoints(:, 1), '-r')
    plot(randPoints(:, 2), '-b')
    plot(randPoints(:, 3), '-g')
    patch(pt(:,1), pt(:,2),pt(:,3))
    lbl = [lbl, '''Plot ', num2str(i), ''','];
    eval(['legend(', lbl, '''Location'', ''Best'')'])
end
```

If instead you want to add the legends for plots in any position, you can use the `'DisplayName'` option for the plots and use their handles in the legend call.

```
figure
hold on
randPoints = rand(20, 3);
pt = rand(3,3)*10;

hold on
h1 = plot(randPoints(:, 1), '-r', 'DisplayName', 'First plot')
h2 = plot(randPoints(:, 2), '-b', 'DisplayName', 'Second plot')
h3 = plot(randPoints(:, 3), '-g', 'DisplayName', 'Third plot')
h4 = patch(pt(:,1), pt(:,2),pt(:,3), 'DisplayName', 'Fourth plot')
legend([h2, h4], 'Location', 'Best') % show the legend entry for the second and fourth plot only for example
```